# Simple bash recursion ambiguity

Tags: bash

I'm writing very simple bash script to change encoding of 
.html files and want to handle directories recursively. 
The function working properly for first level directory only. 
Can you tell me where I'm wrong? Here is me code.

```
#!/bin/bash

handleFiles () { 
 local REGEXP='.+\.html$'
 echo $1
 for f in $1/*
  do
   if  [[ -d $f ]]
      then
       handleFiles "$f"
   elif [[ $f =~ $REGEXP ]]
      then 
       echo "Converting $f"
       enconv -L bg -x UTF-8 "$f" 
   fi
 done
}

# The script show all .html files in test
# enter into subdirectory but not working .. 
handleFiles "test"
```

Here is structure of test directory:

```
test$ tree 
.
├── test.html
└── Untitled Folder
    └── test1.html

1 directory, 2 files
```

When I run the script I get following output:

```
 ./converter.sh 
test
Converting test/test.html
test/Untitled Folder
```

To be the whole story I post my final solution. I hope this will be useful to someone with a similar problem.

```
#!/bin/bash

########################################################
#   This bash script assume directory as a argument
#   and convert all  .html,js and xml files from 
#   windows-1251 encoding into utf-8 encoding. 
#   @author Georgi Naumov 
#   @email gonaumov@gmail.com for contacts and 
#   suggestions. 
########################################################

if [[ $# -ne 1 ]] ; then
    echo "Usage $0 <<directory to change encoding reqursively>>"
    exit 1
fi

handleFiles () { 
 local REGEXP='.+\.(html|js|xml)$'
 for f in "$1"/*
  do
   if  [[ -d "$f" ]]
      then
       handleFiles "$f"
   elif [[ "$f" =~ $REGEXP ]]
      then 
       echo "Converting $f"
       enconv -L bg -x UTF-8 "$f" 
   fi
 done
}

handleFiles "$1"
```

Comment: Is this an exercise or would you be interested in a simpler way of converting your files?

Comment: I'm just write this to convert many files in one directory but want to improve the solution to handle nested directories recursive.

Comment: Quote `$f` with `""` to handle directories with whitespaces (e.g. Untitled Folder).

Comment: I have added "" but test1.html is again not handled.

Comment: Take a look at: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155551/how-to-debug-a-bash-script/155553#155553)

Comment: The answer to the problem was here in your comment. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quote also `$1` to handle whitespaces (e.g. `Untitled Folder`):

```
for f in "$1"/*
```

Comment: Thank you. I just want to know why my solution not working properly.

Answer (score 4):

The whole approach is rather more complicated than necessary. I recommend using `find`:

```
find test -name '*.html' -exec enconv -L bg -x UTF-8 '{}' \;
```

If you want to do it manually, you have to put `$f` in double quotes everywhere (i.e., `"$f"`), or it will break if a directory contains spaces, as you have noticed, because the shell will expand it into two (or more, as the case may be) separate tokens.

Comment: Thus solution is better but I want to know why mine solution don't work +1.

Comment: Put the `$1` in quotes also, i.e. `for i in "$1"/*`, since `$1` will end up containing spaces as well.

Comment: According to [this manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/enconv) `enconv` can take more than one file argument, so changing the `\;` to `+` will probably speed things up, too.